# In timeseries ZingChart, while using appendseriesvalues in realtime, xValue causing issue

Tags: ajax, charts, zingchart

I am trying to create a realtime timeseries graph using ZingChart. But I want it accumulative one in which all points accumulate as data appends. So I am using  "appendseriesvalues" in each ajax poll to append data and m passing data as JSON object as (key, value) pair.

My code is as follows:

```
     var chartData = {
        "show-progress":false,
        "gui":{
            "behaviors":[
                {
                    "id":"ZoomIn",
                    "enabled":"all"
                },
                {
                    "id":"ZoomOut",
                    "enabled":"all"
                },
                {
                    "id":"ShowAll",
                    "enabled":"all"
                }
            ]
        },
    "type":"line",
  //  "utc":true, /* Force UTC time. */
   // "timezone": -5,
    "plotarea": {
      "adjust-layout":true /* For automatic margin adjustment. */
    },
    "scale-x":{
        "values": [],
      "label":{ /* Add a scale title with a label object. */
        "text":"Above is an example of a time-series scale",
      },
      "min-value":1420070400000, /* Unix timestamp for Jan 1, 2015. */
      "step":"second",
      "transform":{ /* Converts your Unix timestamp to a human readable format. */
        "type":"date", /* Set your transform type to "date". */
        "all":"%h:%i:%s" /* Specify your date/time format, using tokens. */
      },
      "line-color":"none",
      "tick":{
          "visible":false
      },
      "zooming":1,
      "item":{
          "font-color":"#000",
          "visible":true
      },
    //  "max-labels":10000,
      "itemsOverlap": true
    },
    "scale-y":{
        "zooming":1,
         "items-overlap": true
    },

    "series":[
        {
            "values":[]
        }
    ],

};

window.onload = function() {
    zingchart.render({
        id: "chartDiv",
        data: chartData,
        height: 600,
        width: "100%"
    });
};

setInterval(flashText, 1000);

function flashText() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         headers: {
             Accept: "application/json",
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
         },
         url: "TestServlet2",
         success:function(data) {                   
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                         zingchart.exec('chartDiv', 'appendseriesvalues', {
                             values: [[key,value]],
                            })


            });

    },
     });

  }
```

If I create using this code, it takes key and value as 2 values in series.I want to plot it as (key,value). Kindly suggest me what am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

If you have not seen it, we do have a [realtime feed](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/loading-data/making-real-time-feeds/) section on our website. For the sake of staying on topic to your question, I will show you how to incorporate the API call into ZingChart.

My first assumption I'm going to make is that the key is a timestamp Number in milliseconds and value is a Number type. I'm making the assumption that key is a timestamp because you have defined the transform object and set a min value as a timestamp.

```
"min-value":1420070400000, /* Unix timestamp for Jan 1, 2015. */
```

If this was not intended, please specify, but I will move forward with the example. Under the assumption that your data being input is correct, the only thing you haven't done is specify the plot index. According to our [appendseriesvalues](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/developers/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__appendseriesvalues) documentation, you must define a plotindex if only updating a single plot. I have used most of your  config to create a chart that plots a [timestamp,value] pair every second using the API method appendseriesvalues.

```js
var chartData = {
  "show-progress":false,
  "gui":{
    "behaviors":[
      {
        "id":"ZoomIn",
        "enabled":"all"
      },
      {
        "id":"ZoomOut",
        "enabled":"all"
      },
      {
        "id":"ShowAll",
        "enabled":"all"
      }
    ]
  },
  "type":"line",
  //  "utc":true, /* Force UTC time. */
  // "timezone": -5,
  "plotarea": {
  "adjust-layout":true, /* For automatic margin adjustment. */
  "margin-right":50
  },
  "scale-x":{
    "values": [],
    "label":{ /* Add a scale title with a label object. */
      "text":"Above is an example of a time-series scale",
    },
    "min-value":1420070400000, /* Unix timestamp for Jan 1, 2015. */
    "step":"second",
    "transform":{ /* Converts your Unix timestamp to a human readable format. */
      "type":"date", /* Set your transform type to "date". */
      "all":"%h:%i:%s" /* Specify your date/time format, using tokens. */
    },
    "line-color":"none",
    "tick":{
      "visible":false
    },
    "zooming":1,
    "item":{
      "font-color":"#000",
      "visible":true
    },
    //  "max-labels":10000,
    "itemsOverlap": true
  },
  "scale-y":{
    "zooming":1,
    "items-overlap": true
  },
  "series":[
    {
      "values":[]
    }
  ]
};
window.onload = function() {
    zingchart.render({
        id: "myChart",
        data: chartData,
        height: 400,
        width: "100%"
    });
};

// variable for incrementing time
var increment = 0;

// Every second add a new datapoint
setInterval(function() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    data.push(Math.random() * 25 + i);
  }
  
  zingchart.exec('myChart', 'appendseriesvalues', {    
    plotindex:0, // The index of the plot if only appending the data on a single plot. 
    values: [[1420070400000 + increment,data]]
  });
  
  increment += 100;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tnxs alot @nardecky for reply. I have changed my code accordingly and both xValue and yValue are correctly plotting now. But on x-axis as data accumulates, x-axis labels not showing for all data points instead only first and last updated data point x-axis label showing. Any suggestion?? :-D

Comment: @PradnyaP I believe this is because you have defined the minValue and step inside your scaleX:{} object. Remove those two lines and let me know if that is your intended functionality.

Comment: Hi @nardecky, when I comment step, after data accumulation my x-axis labels overlaps on each other which I want it to be auto adjusting. For example if initially two adjacent labels differ by 1 second then after some time the difference should 5 seconds or so. what should I do?

Comment: Hey I figured out mistake :D. I made "itemsOverlap": false inside scaleX:{} and it is working just the way i want. Tnxs a lot @nardecky!